# Module installation in D8.3.6 was possible, using D8.3.7 the same module couldn't be installed

Tags: 8

I have installed the "Serial field" module with the file serial-7.x-1.8.zip in D8.3.6
I have tried to install with the same zip file in  D8.3.7 and it is coming wih the error message "serial-7.x-1.8.zip does not contain any .info.yml files. "

I've found general info that  ..yml file is required in D8, but is this requirement raised in D8.3.7 first and in D8.3.6 still was possible w/o ..yml?

Answer (score 2):

> is this requirement raised in D8.3.7 first and in D8.3.6 still was possible w/o ..yml?

No, YAML has been the format for Drupal 8 info files right from early dev versions, way before even the 8.0 release.

> I have installed the "Serial field" module with the file serial-7.x-1.8.zip in D8.3.6

Unless the naming of the archive is an error, and despite being labelled as containing 7.x code, it actually contained 8.x code, I’m afraid you’re mistaken.

Comment: Thanks Clive,  as i've mentioned serial-7.x-1.8.zip was possible to install under D8.3.6 w/o error message and it did work. I did not get the error message "serial-7.x-1.8.zip does not contain any .info.yml files". Strange.

Comment: However seems we have to wait for 8.x version. On the project page in the "Drupal 8 Contrib Porting Tracker » Issues " running a discussion on it for a year, but still not moved to project . Let's close the discussion.Thanks